# AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command' Line 45

Tags: python, discord

I was trying to incorporate Reddit into my bot but every time I run it keeps on giving me this error.

"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 45, in 
@client.command()
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'"

**My Code:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import random
import json
import requests
from replit import db
from keep_alive import keep_alive
import praw 
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id="",
client_secret="",
username="",
password="",
user_agent="")

tz_NY = pytz.timezone('America/New_York') 
datetime_NY = datetime.now(tz_NY)
Times = (datetime_NY.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y"))

c = ('Monday, Febuary 1: **B - Day** \nTuesday, Febuary 2: **A - Day**\nWednesday, Febuary 3: **B - Day**\nThursday, Febuary 4: **A - Day**\nFriday, Febuary 5: **B - Day**') 

e = ('Monday, Febuary 8: **A - Day** \nTuesday, Febuary 9: **B - Day**\nWednesday, Febuary 10: **A - Day**\nThursday, Febuary 11: **B - Day**\nFriday, Febuary 12: **A - Day**') 

foo = ['Jacob', 'Ashkan', 'Zeek', 'Omar', 'Ethan', 'Llani', 'Gabe']
doo = ['1',  '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

client = discord.Client()
bot_prefix = "$"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.command()
async def meme(ctx):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("memes")
    all_subs = []

    top = subreddit.top(Limit = 5)

    for submission in top:
      all_subs.append(submission)

    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)

    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.title

    em = discord.Embed(title = name)

    em.set_image(url = url)

    await ctx.send(embed = em)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$date'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title= Times, description="------", color=0x00ff00)
        embedVar.add_field(name="This Week", value= c, inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Next Week", value= e, inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)

    if message.content.startswith('$sus'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title= 'the sus test', description="------", color=0xFF0000)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Participant", value= random.choice(foo), inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Sus Meter", value= random.choice(doo), inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)

keep_alive()  
client.bot('TOKEN')
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

I tried fixing the client but the @client.commands() is the issue here. (Line 45)

Any help will be much appreciated thanks :)

Comment: What makes you think that your `client` object *does* have a `command` method?  Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the offending values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?  You and the Python run-time system seem to disagree on what `client` is at the exception point.  You need to check the type and value of `client`.

Comment: I also edited the code and the error is on the last three lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is that you are mixing up the diffrence between `bot` and `client`. Those are to diffrent things.
A bot is simpler, it just recivies commands from you and handles them. Meaning it does something. If you want to write in the chat and do more things you need a client.

Besides that you can't create a Bot like that:
`client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)`
The right way would be: `bot = Bot(command_prefix='$')` since you have already imported bot.

The way to go for you would be to stick with the client and instead of commands use:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content == 'someString':
        # do somethng
```

Comment: Thanks again that helped.